# Which cloud region could have the fastest time for a docker image push?

Tags: docker, cloud

**TLDR**
How to know what region in the cloud nearest to docker hub?

**Full details**
From my localhost my network is super slow to push the docker image onto docker hub.

My workaround is to use a cloud machine to do that `docker image push` hopefully that the internet there would be faster.

So my question is which region on the cloud is nearest to docker hub for me to choose?

[My google search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61029378/248616) results little helpful

p.s. 
I also asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61029378/248616)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TLDR

From cloud instance, just go push to docker hub; you will be routed to the best location automatically.

#### Full details

DockerHub is a massive scale and very critical global service.  So, you almost definitely don't have to think about this at all.

There are techniques on cloud hosts (AWS, Azure, GCP) to replicate & host content/services in regions across the globe and route traffic to the closest entry point automatically.  The cloud hosts make this quite easy to do with their managed services (while without them it would be very difficult).

Also, there are many third party providers of technologies like CDNs which do similar things at scale (and they are really good at it).  They are **extremely** frequently used in these cases.

So, again - just go to docker hub and don't think about it.  You will be routed to the best location automatically.

Comment: Then why I image push slowlier than my colleages in another country?

Comment: If you’re on a cloud host machine (e.g. an EC2), I’d be surprised if you are experiencing that unless it’s a very minor region.  They have crazy fast backplanes for networking.  If you’re on your own computer then it’s almost certainly your internet connection and local network.  There will be *millions* of docker containers running on hosts and in kubernetes in every cloud host region, so it’s got to be fast or people would be escalating pretty quick.

Comment: Got what you mean clearly now. Yes it is slow on my local, and pretty fast on cloud machine.